# MVC routing not working as needed

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to set up a custom route in MVC but having a few problems.

This is the config file so far: -

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "inbox",
            url: "inbox",
            defaults: new { controller = "Mail", action = "Inbox", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

This is the link in my view: -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inbox", "inbox")
```

The trouble is the output html is being produces as http://localhost/Home/inbox

I just want it to be http://localhost/inbox

Thanks for any help

Comment: Good man, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of `Html.ActionLink`. With the version you are using, it uses the current context to determine the controller, whereas you want to use the `Mail` controller. So to fix this, change it to explicitly specify the controller like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inbox", "Inbox", "Mail")
```